# How to bail when required_unless is passed in Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have a form with these 3 inputs:

1. a text input named "room1"
2. a checkbox like: "☑ I don't need room 2" and named "oneroom"
3. a text input named "room2"

By default the user needs to input both rooms. But when the checkbox is checked I don't need to check any additional rule for room 2 after `required_if:oneroom,null`. The code I have so far:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
            'room1' => array('required', 'min:3'),
            'room2' => array('bail','required_if:oneclass,null', 'min:3',),
        ]);
```

**this code is simplified for the sake of this question. The original form has many more fields that have the same problem*

When the checkbox is checked and room2 is empty, the `required_if` rule is passed so it doesn't bail and checks `min:3`. But at this point I need Laravel to bail and not check `min:3`. When the checkbox is not checked it does what it supposed to and generates error that says room2 can't be empty if one room is not checked

Is there any way to implement what I'm trying to do without any additional code outside of the validation rules?

Please comment if you need me to clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`'room2' => array('exclude_if:oneclass,value', 'min:3')`

(replace value with whatever value is set in html). This will exclude room2 from validations and won't generate any error messages based on any additional rules. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exclude-if)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$request->validate([
    'room1' => array('required', 'min:3'),
    'room2' => array('bail','required_without:oneclass', 'min:3', 'nullable'),
]);
```

Comment: this won't work if `oneclass` is checked and room2's value is less than 3 characters. it will still generate error. also inferring that the user will keep room2 empty (won't generate error because it is nullable) means that this will work only for text field and not other type of inputs like radio/select